# Using as.numeric, with functions and pipes in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function that looks like this

```
 calc_df <- function(A_df, B_df){
     C_df <- filter(A_df, Type == "Animal") %>% 
         left_join(B_df)  %>%
         as.numeric(C$Count)
```

Where I cannot get the last lime to work, the first 3 work properly, but I would like the last line to take the column "Count" from the new df calculated in the function and make it numeric. (Right now it is a character vector)

** I have to do this at the end of the function because before the filter command, the Count column contains letters and cannot be made as.numeric

Comment: Please provide some reproducible example

Comment: put it in `mutate`?  or `transmutate`

Answer (score 28):

Looks like you're using `dplyr`, and that you want to change or add a column. This is what the `dplyr::mutate` function does.

Replace

```
as.numeric(C$Count)
```

with

```
mutate(Count = as.numeric(Count))
```

to replace the old, non-numeric `Count` column with the coerced-to-numeric replacement.

As to why your code didn't work, there are a few problems:

- `dplyr` is made for working with data frames, and the main dplyr functions (select, filter, mutate, summarize, group_by, *_join, ...) expect data frames as the first argument, and then return data frames. By piping the result of a left join into `as.numeric`, you are really calling `as.numeric(unnamed_data_frame_from_your_join, C$Count)`, which clearly doesn't make much sense.
- You are trying to reference a data frame called `C` inside a definition for a data frame called `C_df`, which I think you mean to be the same thing. There's two issues here: (1) the mismatch between the names `C` and `C_df`, and (2) you can't reference `C_df` inside it's own definition.

Comment: Thank you so much! And extra thanks for explaining everything, I see what I did wrong now.....